# How to sharpen image so that image can read by OCR?

Tags: python, ocr, opencv

I want to sharpen image so that image can be more readable by OCR.

For making it easier to read, I have processed image to B & W with this code.

```
import cv2
im_gray = cv2.imread('your_image_here', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
thresh = 127
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('bw_image.png', im_bw)
```

The output is like this
[image]
Then, when I want to read it by OCR, the output is not accurate. I want to read "443,296" and "72,727". What's the code to sharpen image so that it can be read more accurate?

Comment: How blurry/noisy is the image? There are algorithms for smoothing edges, removing specks, etc., as long as the image has consistently human-readable letters.

Comment: This is plenty sharp for OCR. Tesseract will have no problem recognizing those numbers.

Comment: @mnistic I know it. But, Tesseract can not read 443,296, 72,727, and 24,532,940

Comment: That is probably not an image quality problem. How do you segment your image before recognition?

Answer (score 0):

Sharpening can only get you so far.  If you really want to get additional detail, one thing you could explore are super-resolution neural networks.

One you could easily try to get an idea of how good the technology is is letsenhance.io, but based on your question you'll probably want one you can run locally.  I'm not sure the best one but perhaps https://github.com/alexjc/neural-enhance

Comment: this maybe works for natural things, but what I found is that it tends to scramble human readable information.  perhaps there are more advanced analytical alternatives to 'sharpening'?

Comment: Also, my understanding is that the neural net is a stack of parameterized functions applied to convolutions...so you can't get anywhere with a neural net that you can't get with morph ops.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try dilating the characters simply and see if it improves your OCR.

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

More here about Morphological Transformations in OpenCV: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html